# build android source: which module should I build?

Tags: android, android-source

I did some modification to file `/frameworks/base/core/java/com/android/internal/os/ZygoteConnection.java` (just add some log) on android-4.4.2_r2 and now I'd like to build as small a module as possible.

I tried `make frameworks` but it said `nothing to be done for frameworks`.

So which module should I build? And how do you know that? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's `make framework2`

From frameworks/base/Android.mk, lines 339-352:

```
# Build part 2 of the framework library.
# ============================================================
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := framework2
LOCAL_MODULE_CLASS := JAVA_LIBRARIES
LOCAL_NO_STANDARD_LIBRARIES := true
LOCAL_STATIC_JAVA_LIBRARIES := framework-base
LOCAL_DX_FLAGS := --core-library

# Packages to include, use \* wildcard to include descendants.
LOCAL_JAR_PACKAGES := com\* javax\*

include $(BUILD_JAVA_LIBRARY)
```